# How to use settimeout method in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to know how to use `setTimeout()` method. Basically, I want to click on the element after some seconds and after that perform something.

So My code is as below,

```
class SomeComponent extends React.PureComponent {
    on_first_render = () => {
        this.somemethod_called();
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.props.handle_click(52, 16);
        },0);
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.props.handle_click(522, 352);
         }, 0)

         setTimeout(() => {
             const input = document.querySelector('input[type=text] 
                           [name=somename]');
             input && input.blur();
         }, 700);
```

As seen from above code, same `handle_click()` method is called in two `setTimeout()` methods and after 7 seconds I search for input element in the document and remove focus from it.

I feel this is clumsy and not right approach... Could someone let me know how to do it in another way which is not repeated like this.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you _really_ trying to do? You shouldn't mix `document.querySelector()` with React in general; why not do whatever `handle_click()` does directly? Also, `{52, 16}` is not valid Javascript...

Comment: i have used queryselector instead of state since i didnt want to use state passed from other component and modify the core code for the less used component....also this is done in one statement and can be removed easily later. i have edited my question to fix typos. this input element appears in a dialog after click has been done so i use settimeout to wait until that element appears and perform blur. and handle click is used in set timeout because first time it clicks a point and called second time it creates a line  at the given coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As things are, your `setTimeout`s aren't waiting for anything; you're queuing three timeouts that will resolve after 0, 0, and 700 msecs respectively.

Although I'm not quite sure what you're after in the end, or if you're doing things in a very idiomatic React way, I'd suggest using `async`/`await` and a "delay" helper function:

```js
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const onFirstRender = async () => {
  this.somemethod_called();
  await delay(100);
  this.props.handle_click(52, 16);
  await delay(100);
  this.props.handle_click(522, 352);
  await delay(700);
  const input = document.querySelector("input[type=text][name=somename]");
  if (input) {
    input.blur();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using setTimeOut, you can use debounce to make delay in any operation.

```
var SearchBox = React.createClass({
  componentWillMount: function () {
     this.delayedCallback = _.debounce(function (event) {
       // "event.target" is accessible now
     }, 1000);
  },

  onChange: function (event) {
    event.persist();
    this.delayedCallback(event);
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
      <input type="search" onChange={this.onChange} />
    );
  }

});
```

for more detail go through this module 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-debounce-input

Comment: That's not really what OP is asking for, if I understand things correctly...